# I can't install Codelite on kali linux

Tags: debian, sudo, codelite

I am trying to install Codelite compiler on kali linux but I can't. I tried to install gtk 3+ but it doesn't work with that either ... I don't know what to do anymore, I'm desperate.

Commands I typed:

```
sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
```

=

```
Warning: apt-key is deprecated. Manage keyring files in trusted.gpg.d instead (see apt-key (8)).
Executing: /tmp/apt-key-gpghome.9KZU1WEkrx/gpg.1.sh --fetch-keys http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc
gpg: key request from 'http://repos.codelite.org/CodeLite.asc'
gpg: key 6856E1DB1AC82609: "David Hart (codelite key) <david@codelite.co.uk>" unchanged
gpg: Total number examined: 1
gpg: unedited: 1
```

//

```
sudo apt-add-repository 'deb https://repos.codelite.org/ubuntu/ buster devel'
```

= nothing

//

```
sudo apt-get install codelite
```

=

```
Reading package list ... Done
Dependency tree generation ... Done
Read status information ... Done
Some packages cannot be installed. This can mean
that an impossible situation has been requested or, if you are
using a development distribution, which some packages required
have not yet been created or have been removed from Incoming.
The following information can help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unsatisfied dependencies:
  codelite: Depends: liblldb-7 (> = 1: 7 ~ svn298832-1 ~) but is not installable
             Recommend: gdb
             Recommend: lldb (> = 3.4) but not about to be installed
             Recommend: nodejs but not about to be installed
             Recommend: clang-tools but not about to be installed
E: Unable to fix problems, there are bad packages blocked.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to install Codelite from a software source that is specific to Debian buster (Debian 10), however the version of Kali Linux that you are using is based on the next version of Debian, Debian bullseye, so you are getting an unmet dependencies error message when trying to install it. The solution to this problem is to install a version of Codelite that is compatible with the same version of Debian that your Kali Linux is based on.

Codelite IDE is a package in the repositories of the current stable version of Debian bullseye (Debian 11). You can use apt to install this package. To install this package in Kali Linux open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install codelite codelite-plugins
``
```